# CRCs of files do not match in python

Tags: python, wildcard, crc

I've copied image.img to /dev/sdc using dd command. I have generated CRC on the file and file copied to compact card. But the CRC's do not match. How can I ensure that the image copied to card is correct and not corrupted.                                                                  This is my code snippet.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import zlib

    def crc(fileName):
        return "%X"%(zlib.crc32(open(fileName,"rb").read()) & 0xFFFFFFFF)

    def compare(cr1, crc2):
        if crc1 == crc2:
            return "CRC mtached"
        else :
            return "CRC not Equal"

    crc1 = crc(fileName = "image.img")
    print "Generated file CRC", crc1

    crc2 = crc(fileName = "/dev/sdc")
    print "Copied file CRC", crc2

    print compare(crc1, crc2)
```

Comment: afaik dd will not necesarilly create zero bytes ... so there is random noise maybe (I dont know) ...  also make sure you called `sync` after to make sure the write buffer has completely flushed to the sd card

Comment: You dd'd literally to /dev/sdc? That's the raw device name, not the file system on the device. .... And if you did this as root and it succeeded, you've blown the sd card file system away. On the positive side, your crc check is correct for regular files.